# The coverage and pipeline badges are not appearing on PyPI

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, pypi

We have few libraries on PyPI server. Their code for general setup and interface is the same. In a couple of repos [scikit-surgercore](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-surgerycore/) and [scikit-surgeryutils](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-surgeryutils/) the badges of pipeline and coverage are not visible whereas in the other repo [scikit-surgerydavinci](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-surgerydavinci/) all the badges are shown. It is strange because the links are working fine but only the badge is not appearing.

I checked the setup.cfg in projects which is reading description from README.rst. The code part for badges is same for both working and non working repos. I checked the gitlab-server to search for `.svg` images but couldnt find them.

My questions is why badges are not appearing. How PyPI get the badges. Any help on how to fix them? The fix should not be very difficult because the links are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The images are not there. Compare

https://weisslab.cs.ucl.ac.uk/WEISS/SoftwareRepositories/SNAPPY/scikit-surgerydavinci/badges/master/coverage.svg

and

https://weisslab.cs.ucl.ac.uk/WEISS/SoftwareRepositories/SNAPPY/scikit-surgerycore/badges/master/coverage.svg

The second URL returns Error 404 Not Found. Either fix URLs in all `README.rst` or fix the site to return images.

Comment: Ohh okay you are right, I tried in incognito mode and found out that the second link is not working. So it has to do something with repo privileges. If I am logged in then both links work for  me. If I am not login to gitlab then the second link will not work. Although All the above repos are public

Comment: So on going to repo > settings > CI / CD > and expanding General Pipeline section. Scroll down and you will see the three ways for including pipeline and coverage badges in your project. I think that gitlab or pypi updated thats why the old style is not working. I am not sure though I will check more and report back.

Comment: Update: The system is not changed. The link in above location is fine but it has the same behaviour, i.e. working if I am logged in and not working if I try to access it in incognito mode. Could any one suggest what permissions are causing it not to appear when user is not registered for repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and the problem is in permission to the repo pipeline as suggested by @phd. It was tricky because the file `.svg` does not exist in the project or in the Gitlab server but it is created by Gitlab on the fly for each project.
On changing pipelines permission from `Only Project Members` to `Everyone with Access` fix the problem. The settings are located at `Gitlab-Repo > Settings > Visibility, project features, permissions > Click Expand and in Repo section change Pipelines`

[image]